# Python 2.7 scoping issue with variable/method when placed inside a function

Tags: python

I'm new to python and notice this code works when written without being put inside a function.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = lambda: None

def setup_browser():
   # unnecessary code removed
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    return driver

setup_browser()
driver.set_window_size(1000, 700)
driver.get("https://icanhazip.com/")
```

As shown above, I get this error:

```
`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'set_window_size'
```

My reading is that driver is not being updated before it is called. Why is this?

Comment: `driver = setup_browser()`

Comment: I get it now. Without that the return value goes nowhere. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that inside of `setup_browser()` you're setting a local variable named `driver`, but you are not modifying the global variable `driver`. To do that, you need to use the `global` keyword:

```
def setup_browser():
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    return driver
```

However, overriding the `driver` global variable and returning it at the same time is redundant. It would be better to not define `driver` globally as a null function, but to assign it directly. E.g.,

```
from selenium import webdriver

def setup_browser():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    return driver

driver = setup_browser()
driver.set_window_size(1000, 700)
driver.get("https://icanhazip.com/")
```